# How can I check component/page is published to which target?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, core-services

I have a situation where I have to find out those publication targets which are deleted some time back in order to unpublish those components/pages which are published and now they are not being unpublished and further not able to delete.  (In this case publication targets are not known)
I am using coreservice 2011/2013.

Comment: Hi Rahul. If my answer is not what you're looking for, you might want to ask this over at the Tridion Stack Exchange site: http://tridion.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can see which target a page or component is published to by clicking on Where Used and then the 'Published to' tab. If you want to find all pages and components published to a publication target, then I think you'd need to write some code with the core service. Something like the answer here should work:

https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15090/getting-list-of-published-pages-againtst-a-specific-target-type-in-specific-busi